# What happens to the data in memory deallocated by free()?

Tags: c, memory, free

What happens to the data that is present in a memory location that has just been freed by a `free()` ? Is that data also deleted and the memory will now have a garbage value ? Or that data still persists there untill a new data is stored in that memory location (in future) ?

I mean, for code below:

```
int *ptr;
ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
*ptr = 1;
 // Suppose ptr = 2000
 //Free now
free(ptr);
// My question is what is the value stored in memory address 2000 now ?
// Is it still '1' or some garbage value ?
```

Comment: The standard doesn't specify that. It only says that some usages of `ptr` after the call to `free` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Both scenarios you mentioned are possible amongst many others including accessing the data via that pointer results in a segmentation fault.  It is undefined behavior (UB).  [Let_It_Go](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let_It_Go_(Disney_song))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result is unpredictable.  There are several options that can happen.  The point is that you cannot rely on any behavior of the memory released by `free()`

Some examples:

- the memory can be untouched (remain the same as it is with the same data).
- It can be given to another memory allocation, in which case it can be written over at any point.
- It can be zeroed.
- The page containing the memory can be returned to the OS, removing it from the memory map of your process, making your program crash if you try to access it.

Comment: With the note that it's extremely, *extremely* unlikely that it will get zeroed out. Even in the last case it will most likely sit as it was for a while, allowing any kernel-level process to read it at will.

Comment: some memory allocators zero out free'd memory, either for security or to prepare it for allocations that expect zeroed memory.  Some do other mysterious stuff that we can only speculate about.

Comment: Same goes for allocation for security reasons. When the program asks for some memory, OS cannot just give a portion of free memory. That memory (or page) may be owned by OS or a critical process before the allocation and giving the memory without modifying/zeroing would make the last owner vulnerable.

Comment: I just found out that on x86 and x86_64, linux kernel 3.18.1 zeroes memory on call to `brk`, which `malloc` calls. So, everytime `malloc` requests memory from OS, the returned memory is zeroed. Note that `malloc` usually request more from OS and `malloc` and `free` have their own memory management. So calls to any of them may not result in a syscall, so you cannot guarantee their value. But  you can guarantee that it's either zero, or *your* garbage.

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not the value is overwritten is undefined.  Once `free` is called it is allowed to leave the memory as-is or it can overwrite it, but if you are interested in security you should overwrite it yourself before deallocating it.  Speaking of deallocation, `free` doesn't have to give the memory back to the operating system, and in fact in many cases it won't, instead it will keep the memory allocated to your program so that the next time you call `malloc` it can simply give you back the same memory and avoid having to make more system calls, since the time it takes for memory allocation from the operating system is generally considered a less efficient use of resources than the program keeping a bit more memory allocated than it needs.

Comment: You know that dynamic memory management is managed by the SO. Then, although it may be good practice to delete sensible data contained into memory before to free it, you know that who has control of the operating system may know all data it manages! Rather I think that is good practice to destroy sensible data immediately after they have been used, making this you decrease the time in which  the data are visible!

Answer (score 1):

I know that using the C free() function the memory used is released, but neither the pointer, nor the value contained in the memory is modified! free() only tells that the memory may be used for other purposes. (It may be some libraries implementations clean the freed memory or the pointer value, but this should not be the standard!)

I tried the code below with gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2

```
int main(void)
{
    int *i,j;

    i=malloc(100*sizeof(int));

    for(j=0;j<100;j++)
        i[j]=j+1;

    printf("%p %d\n",i,i[0]);

    free(i);

    printf("%p %d\n",i,i[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

The output results (as I expected) is:

```
0x1de2010 1
0x1de2010 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Malloc() is a library function. The answer depends upon how the library is implemented.

Most (if not all) mallocs prefix a header to the memory block returned. This is usually modified.

Some mallocs append a trailer to the memory block and write something to it. This is used to detect buffer overruns.

Some frees() will overwrite the write the returned memory with some bit pattern to detect subsequent writes.

There are a lot of mallocs out there that you can download and link with your application so you can get nearly any behavior you want by linking the malloc you want with your application.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the compiler. If you are using gcc then after free value of that memory is become 0.

Here is a sample code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main ( void )
{
        int *ptr = NULL;
        ptr = malloc (sizeof(int));
        *ptr = 5;
        printf ( "\n value of *ptr = %d", *ptr );
        free ( ptr );
        printf ( "\n value of *ptr = %d", *ptr );

        return ( 0 );
}
```

o/p:

```
./a.out

 value of *ptr = 5
 value of *ptr = 0

 ./a.out

 value of *ptr = 5
 value of *ptr = 0

./a.out

 value of *ptr = 5
 value of *ptr = 0
```

Comment: @Colonel may i know the reason for -1.

Comment: I think reason for the downwote is that gcc doesn't guarantee this. It may depend on glibc build flags and gcc optimization flags, or it may be only a coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

Dereferencing a `free`d pointer leads to undefined behavior, which means anything is allowed to happen.

Most likely, you'll get some garbage value, but you might also trigger a segmentation fault, which will crash your program. Even so, neither of those behaviors are guaranteed, and you shouldn't rely on them.