# C freeing array isn't working

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, free

Here's my code. I'm creating an array, giving the elements some values, and then freeing and printing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    // malloc the array
    int* array = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*3);

    // give some values
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++) array[i] = 1 + i*i;

    // attempt to free 
    free(array+0);
    free(array+1);
    free(array+2);

    // print array elements
    for(i=0; i<3; i++) printf("%d , ", array[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

It only frees the first and second element (printing random numbers), but the third element keeps there. What shall I do to fix this? And if I'm doing something wrong (such as using free incorrectly) please point that out too. Thanks.

Comment: This is wrong as pointed by zenith, but even if it weren't, dereferencing a `free`d pointer sounds like undefined behavior

Comment: one `free()` per `malloc()`, you are freeing thre times more than expected.  malloc/free deal with regions of memory, they don't know about how you have structured the regions.  malloc needs to know the size of the region, but that expression is evaluated (yielding a number) before it is actually called.  if you do one malloc, you only have to do one free(with the pointer you received from malloc as parameter).

Answer (score 5):

You can't free elements of an array one by one.

You have to pass the exact same pointer to `free` that `malloc` gave you.

Comment: And don't cast `malloc()`.

Comment: Thanks guys. Still get the same result.

Comment: @FeloVilches Accessing `array` after you have freed it is undefined behavior. I.e. your values may or may not be there after that.

Comment: @zenith okay so, should I just trust the array was freed, even if some of the original values are being printed? (I changed the code using your suggestions)

Comment: @FeloVilches Yes. `free` doesn't overwrite the deallocated data in any way.

Answer (score 2):

C keeps track of allocated memory behind the scenes. If you want to free a chunk you have malloced, you need to pass in the pointer to the start of that chunk of memory. You should be using:

```
free(array);
```

Also, you should not cast malloc.

Answer (score 2):

`free(array+0)` has deallocated the whole array of `sizeof(int)*3`, the following two `free()` calls would cause undefined behavior (see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/).

> void free (void* ptr);
>
> Deallocate memory block
>
> A block of memory
> previously allocated by a call to malloc, calloc or realloc is
> deallocated, making it available again for further allocations.
>
> If ptr does not point to a block of memory allocated with the above
> functions, it causes undefined behavior.
>
> If ptr is a null pointer, the function does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Also, please note that accessing a memory region after it is free()ed results in undefined behavior. [What happens to the data in memory deallocated by free()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29586074/what-happens-to-the-data-in-memory-deallocated-by-free)

So you cant really conclude something by printing the value stored in a memory region which is already freed.

Answer (score 0):

Show right code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    // malloc the array
    int* array = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*3);

    // give some values
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++) 
        array[i] = 1 + i*i;



     for(i=0; i<3; i++) //current values
        printf("%d , ", array[i]);
     putchar('\n');
    // attempt to free 
    free(array);

    // print array elements
    for(i=0; i<3; i++) //values after exposure functions free()
        printf("%d , ", array[i]);
    putchar('\n');


    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    // malloc the array
    // <-- allocated 12 bytes of memory in the heap
    // <-- set a pointer-to-int 'array' to point to that memory
    // <-- in C, should NOT cast returned value from malloc (and family of functions)
    int* array = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*3);

    // give some values
    // <-- set allocated memory in the heap 
    //     to 0x0000001 0x00000002 0x00000005
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++) array[i] = 1 + i*i;

    // attempt to free
    // <-- unallocate all 12 bytes
    free(array+0);

    // <-- corrupt the heap, this not an address pointer
    // <-- returned by malloc (or family of functions)
    free(array+1);

    // <-- corrupt the heap some more, this is not an address pointer
    // <-- returned by malloc (or family of functions)
    free(array+2);

    // print array elements
    // <-- trying to print using array as a base address ptr,
    // <-- when array no longer points to any allocated memory
    // <-- array still points into the heap, but the 
    // <-- 12 bytes are already returned to the OS
    // <-- so the program should not be accessing those 12 bytes
    for(i=0; i<3; i++) printf("%d , ", array[i]);
    return 0;
} // end function: main
```